# Why the statements oDiv[i].style.z-index = arr[i][3]; didn't work?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had consoled arr[i][3] and I'm sure that it was absolutely correct，else,others statements worked and I don't know why.
The code was listed as follows

```
    for(var i = 0; i<oDiv.length;i++){
                arr.push([getAttr(oDiv[i],"left"),getAttr(oDiv[i],"top"),
getAttr(oDiv[i],"opacity"),getAttr(oDiv[i],"z-index")]);
                //console.log(arr);  it shows a correct value;
                }

            oBtn[0].onclick = function(){

                arr.unshift(arr[arr.length-1]);
                arr.pop();

                for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
                    oDiv[i].style.left = arr[i][0];
                    oDiv[i].style.top = arr[i][1];
                    oDiv[i].style.opacity = arr[i][2];   //these three statements worked;
                    oDiv[i].style.z-index = arr[i][3];  //it doesn't work.
                }

            }
```

Comment: Use `style.zIndex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> oDiv[i].style.z-index = arr[i][3];
> ```

The `-` is the [subtraction operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2). It cannot appear in an [identifier](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6).

Use camelCase for hyphenated CSS properties.

```
 oDiv[i].style.zIndex = arr[i][3];
```

Comment: Thanks，the problem is solved.